# How to add label or text to the google map's specific location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps, angular2-google-maps

Im working on "[angular2-google-maps](https://angular-maps.com/)" and I want to add custom text to a given point in map. I was trying polyline but it seems its not allows to add labels to it. Please let me know your suggestions. Thanks very much in advance.